# Allow multiple language characters in RewriteRule

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

i already have some RewriteRule for my engine and now i want add foreign languages in url , so i must change my rewrite engine rule too but i can't figure how i must do this.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ ?lang=$1&page=$2&cat=$3&pNumb=$4 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ ?lang=$1&page=$2&pNumb=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/opt/([A-Za-z0-9_\:{},"'><.-]+)/?$ ?lang=$1&page=$2&opt=$3 [NC]




RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ ?lang=$1&page=$2&cat=$3&cont=$4 [NC]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ ?lang=$1&page=$2&cat=$3 [NC]



RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ ?lang=$1&page=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ ?lang=$1 [NC]
```

this is my current rules, i want opt variable allowed foreign characters too.
in this line

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/opt/([A-Za-z0-9_\:{},"'><.-]+)/?$ ?lang=$1&page=$2&opt=$3 [NC]
```

please show how i must add this kind of rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [B] flag: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Also, if you're using [B] to avoid escaping, you should also be able to just use (.+) instead of that enormous list of characters.

Comment: The difficulty is that ?lang=$1&page=$2 is not a valid URL for any values of $1 and $2. What is that query string supposed to be appended to? A query string must follow a valid URI.